# How to implements PortForwarder in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

In source code `k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelete/server/portforward` , there is an Interface

```golang
// PortForwarder knows how to forward content from a data stream to/from a port in a pod.
type PortForwarder interface {
    // PortForwarder copies data between a data stream and a port in a pod.
    PortForward(name string, uid types.UID, port int32, stream io.ReadWriteCloser) error
}
```

How could I implement it ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That only has to be implemented by new runtime plugins and that basically doesn't happen anymore because CRI exists and it's better to implement that specification instead.

Comment: I'm trying to make a proxy server，just like   kubectl --> proxy ---> k8s api server, so I can do anything in Proxy and at the same time the origin k8s api server also works normal.